# Multi-Factor Authentification?

Tags: security

I am in the process of looking at the features of CiviCRM and have come across a security question.

Does CiviCRM have multi-factor authentification (MFA)?

I tried looking into the website and public posts, but have not found an answer yet.

Answer (score 4):

CiviCRM doesn't because it doesn't control logins. Whatever CMS you're using will have something for it (e.g. Drupal/Wordpress/Joomla).